# SQL Section: Only Names, that are exists on one entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an DB with two columns names and day.
I want to find all names that exists only once at day x.
Really simple, but my brain doesn't work .

I thought a simple self join would do this but..

```
SELECT d1.id 
FROM day AS d1 
JOIN day AS d2 ON d1.id = d2.id 
AND d1.day=3 AND d1.day != d2.day
```

```
Example:
| name     | day          |
| -------- | ------------ |
| First    | 1            |
| First    | 2            |
| First    | 3            |
| Second   | 3            |
```

and want only return Second

Comment: Have you tried changing to a LEFT JOIN where right side IS NULL? Or NOT EXISTS? You do not reference `names` column at all in your attempted SQL but you reference `id` column which is not previously mentioned. Please add the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Would a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` help? `SELECT ID from myTable where day = 3 group by name having count(*)  = 1` ?

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE `day` (
  `name` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `day` int(2) NOT NULL)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following get your expected results? Select the desired rows and check rows for other days do *not exist*

```
Select d.name
from Day d
where d.day=3
and not exists (
    select * from Day d2
    where d2.name = d.name and d2.day != d.day
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i tried a similar one before, this give me all with day=n but not exclusive the one that are also exists on another days

Comment: You need to add sample data and desired results.

Comment: added example to question

Comment: @risiko24 Have edited above to use a `not exists` criteria

Answer (score 0):

Using windows function and alternative count distinct approach.

```
WITH all_names AS (
SELECT *,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY day) +
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY day DESC) - 1 AS day_count
FROM days d
WHERE d.day <= 3
)
SELECT a.name
FROM all_names a
WHERE a.day_count = 1 AND a.day =3
GROUP BY name;
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9006c1c70d461c0290ae437eb9d697a6)